# How to highlight selected menu item in css only?

Tags: css

I need to get the menu item to remain highlighted when a user clicks on it, of each different page..? It must be CSS only.

CSS:

```
.topplinker span:hover, .index .shjem, .kontakt .skontakt, .byggdrifter .sbyggdrifter, .om .som { 
background-color: #fffcd9;
border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="index"><p class="topplinker"> 
<span class="shjem"><a href="/">Hjem</a></span>
<span class="skontakt"><a href="/kontakt">Kontakt</a></span>
<span class="sbyggdrifter"><a href="/byggdrifter">Byggdrifter</a></span>
<span class="som"><a href="/om">Om</a></span> 
</p>
```

So now the code depends on the body class to be unique for each page to work. But I wants it to be working without using the body class to highlight each menu item. Any suggestions..?

Best regards

Comment: if you want to make it with pure css you should use radiobuttons with styling.

Answer (score 0):

use ul and li.
then use onclick function to make li active.

Comment: the problem that it was asked for pure css solution :)

Comment: Yes, I need a "CSS only" solution.

Comment: sorry my bad. For doing that you have to use visited attribute in css..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with CSS, If you click on the URL i just change color.

> FYI, if pages loads while clicking those url means you have right based on Router URL only.

```css
#toggle1:checked ~ .control-me,
#toggle2:checked ~ .control-me,
#toggle3:checked ~ .control-me,
#toggle4:checked ~ .control-me {
    background: violet;
}

.menuitem {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body class="index">
  <p class="topplinker"> 
      <a href="javascript:;">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="menuitem" id="toggle1" class="menuitem" />
          <span class="control-me shjem">Hjem</span>
        </label>
      </a>
      <a href="javascript:;">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="menuitem" id="toggle2" class="menuitem" />
          <span class="control-me skontakt">Kontakt</span>
        </label>
      </a>
      <a href="javascript:;">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="menuitem" id="toggle3" class="menuitem" />
          <span class="control-me sbyggdrifter">Byggdrifter</span>
        </label>
      </a>
      <a href="javascript:;">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="menuitem" id="toggle4" class="menuitem" />
          <span class="control-me som">Om</span>
        </label>
      </a>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Issue with this, the highlighted color suppose to REMAIN on the selected link after click. Also, this solution only makes the borders linkable, but the links background-area is not linkable, witch makes it impossible to use.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS only solution:**

```css
.topplinker {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

a:active, a:hover {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* EDIT */
a:visited {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="topplinker"> 
<span class="shjem"><a href="/">Hjem</a></span>
<span class="skontakt"><a href="/kontakt">Kontakt</a></span>
<span class="sbyggdrifter"><a href="/byggdrifter">Byggdrifter</a></span>
<span class="som"><a href="/om">Om</a></span> 
</p>
```

- See for more selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Comment: This will only change the color on click and hover, but when the  pointer moves away from the linkarea the color changes back to original color. It suppose to REMAIN the highlighted color for each page it loads.

Comment: you mean, if the link was already `visited`?

Comment: Yes, the current menu item must be highlighted on the actual page.

Comment: You just have to use the `:visited` selector for an anchor tag. I already updated the answer.

Comment: Only the clicked menu-item suppose to be highlighted. When the user moves to another menu-item, the highlighted menu-style suppose to follow each menu-item when clicked, but when the user clicks on new menu-items the effect suppose to only affect the active menu-item, leaving the other menu-items back to original color.